# flutter web on s3 static hosting not able to display images

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

When I do a

```
flutter web build
```

and created a static website on s3, the flutter app tries to access images via /assets but the `build` puts them inside 2 nested assets folders

```
build
  web
    assets
      assets
        github.png
        other images
```

I put a sample build on github where the assets are
https://github.com/matthewchung74/test/tree/main/assets

and the build assets are here
https://github.com/matthewchung74/test/tree/main/build/web/assets/assets

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I am just doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When using , , or , the browser automatically blocks access to pixels when it knows that an image is coming from another site and the CORS policy disallows access to data.

WebGL requires access to the image data in order to be able to render the image. Therefore, images to be rendered using WebGL must only come from servers that have a CORS policy configured to work with the domain that serves your application.

For more information:
[Displaying images on the web](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images)

Comment: Thanks, I understand the problem better now, and reworded. cors was indeed a problem earlier before posting.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? @foobar8675

Comment: it's been a while, so not 100% but I think what I did was to access images via the pubspec like this  https://gist.github.com/yhatpub/67535e9e0b28654454d7bcb6673acb56 so when building, inside the folder structure looks like build/web/assets/image

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So I figured it out (for my case at least).  If I have an image file "assets/images/foo.png", then AssetImage let's me do this "AssetImage('images/foo.png')", which works when I use `flutter run` but not when I do `flutter build ...`.  I ended up correcting the call to "AssetImage('assets/images/foo.png')" and now everything works.